# How to configure Log4J2 for multiple modules?

Tags: java, logging, module, configuration, log4j2

My project consists of multiple modules (JDK Java 12).
Each module can run on its own and have a separate log4j2.xml that contains Loggers and Appenders.

I admit that this is my first attempt at using log4j2 in that direction.
I want to know how I should write the log4j2.xml.

I tried to use the System for setting the property but without success.

`System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", "log4j2-A.xml,log4j2-B.xml,log4j2-C.xml");`

Eclipse doesn't find the files when they are on other projects.

### Structure of the project:

```
Module1:

-   Module2
-   Module3
-   Module4
```

I want the project to run with the configuration of all the modules, and want to avoid copy-paste of all Loggers and Appenders from each module's log4j2.xml into the project-specific log4j2.xml file.

While integrating the modules, the project runs with a log4j2.xml from one of the composing modules (the first one in the module path).

Comment: It sounds like you're using `System.setProperty` in your code which is likely not working because log4j2 is already loaded before you set the property.

Comment: So the problem is that my modules are all using one single log4j2.xml, even if I try to change the properties. It follow that the solutions is some way of configure the xml file, unknow to me.

Comment: Try using the -D JVM command line option to set the system property instead.

Comment: That is something I prefere to do not. Because I use Eclipse to avoid command line (lazy me!)  and because, after that, i have to manually update the property files to avoid manually update the log4j2.xml .

Comment: Ok, then try setting your property in a static block before you initialize log4j2.

Comment: It work. It's not what I wanted at the beginning (I was trying to do all this by XML), but I certainly don't want to complain about it.